# Should I use arraylist or write directly to database?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I want to read fixed length records in a text file that I want to load into a database.

I start with

```bsh
$Content  = Get-Content –Path C:\ps_test_in\*\ -Filter *.txt.
```

Should I move each field into an array or array list looping through content
then loop through the array writing to the database?

Or write to the database as loop through the first time?

This is a sample input line.

```
ZASC 01 46446464646465666064644644600000000000300900000000100000000001834342000000000000‌​00000000Bruce Bear 111 ST IA 4
```

Thousands of records with be read.

```bsh
$FileName = Get-ChildItem –Path C:\ps_test_in -Filter *.txt
$Content  = Get-Content –Path C:\ps_test_in\*\ -Filter *.txt
Write-Host "________________________________________________________" 

for ($i=0; $i -lt $FileName.Count; $i++){
    Write-Host $FileName[$i]
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $Content.Count; $j++){
        $Type             = $Content[$j].substring(0,1)
        $CustomerName     = $Content[$j].substring(12,20)
        if ($CustomerName.Trim().Length -ne 0){
            if ($Type -eq "z") {
                <# Split Fields Off of Input Files #>
                $AccountID        = $Content[$j].substring(22,11)
                $stuff1           = $Content[$j].substring() 
                $JobName          = $Content[$j].substring() 
                $JobCode          = $Content[$j].substring() 
                $JobDD            = $Content[$j].substring() 
                $CustomerName     = $Content[$j].substring()
                $Address01        = $Content[$j].substring() 
                $Address02        = $Content[$j].substring()                
                $Address03        = $Content[$j].substring()
                $Address04        = $Content[$j].substring()
                $CityStateZip     = $Content[$j].substring()
                $RecNum           = $Content[$j].substring() 

                #Write Records to Database
                $insert_stmt = 
                   "INSERT INTO FD_MRDF(
                       AcctNumber,
                       stuff1,
                       JobName,
                       JobNumber,
                       OutputGrp,
                       Name,
                       Address01,Address02,Address03,Address04,
                       CityStateZip,
                       RecordNumber
                   ) 
                   VALUES (
                      '$AccountID',
                      '$stuff1', 
                      '$JobName',           
                      '$JobCode',           
                      '$JobDD',             
                      '$CustomerName',     
                      '$Address01','$Address02','$Address03','$Address04',        
                      '$CityStateZip',     
                      '$RecNum'            

                   )" 
                   $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
                   $cmd.CommandText = $insert_stmt
                   $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            }                               
        }                                                        
    }

    Write-Host "________________________________________________________"    
}
Write-Host $Content.Count 
$conn.Close()
```

Comment: This depends on the format of the text files.  Can you paste some sample lines?

Comment: _database_ is very vague. Can you be more specific and perhaps show the technologies you will be using to load said data. 1000's is not that much depending on the break down. You _could_ build a series of INSERT statements I suppose. Some utilities could read the file straight in possibly as well.

Comment: ZASC   01                4644646464646566606464464460000000000030090000000010000000000183434200000000000000000000Bruce Bear                    111 ST                        IA 4

Comment: mssql. I found a way to build an insert statement. $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 
$conn.Open()

        $insert_stmt =                                                                                                $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $insert_stmt
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.Close()

Comment: I found a way to split the fields out to store the data into local powershell fields.  I want to get those local fields into mssql table.

Comment: $Select01         = $Content[$j].substring(14,3)

Comment: All updates for the question should be added to the question using `Edit`. Comments are for comments and questions